# Is it possible to use Open Office where applications are calling Word OLE objects?

Tags: windows, ms-word, openoffice-writer

Ok so we purchased a piece of software that opens, updates, and closes Word documents stored on a file server. I have spoken with the developers of the software inquiring about using other Office systems instead of Microsoft Office. They informed me that they are calling in code Word OLE objects to open, update, and close documents. Which then inherently calls WINWORD.exe.

Is it possible to configure Windows 7 to open oowriter instead of winword when winword.exe is being called?

The problem we are facing is that new clients don't have Microsoft Office they are running Open Office.

Comment: I doubt it. When I was working with Excel files, there was an Interop method (using Excel on the client site), but I went with OOXML instead since it was faster and didn't require any version of Office. You may look into something like that.

Comment: Ok thanks we are currently working on our own system so hopefully we can roll that out quickly enough. Plus I am sure the methods that interact with the document aren't even related to open office.

Comment: If you're working with XLSX/DOCX/any 2007+ format of Word files, I would recommend [OOXML SDK 2.0](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=5124). It is very fast (reads 10,000+ excel rows in about 30 seconds) and parses through docs like their native XML.

Comment: Interesting I will check that out thanks!

Comment: Well I would love to download it but it seems Microsoft needs to fix their site first.